# Error al conectar a servidor alterno en SQL server

Tags: sql-server, servidor, virtualbox

Estoy haciendo una tarea de mi escuela en donde tengo que hacer una instancia de un servidor reflejado, el problema es que cuando quiero indicarle cual será la instancia del servidor reflejado me aparece que no lo encuentra y me aparece este error.
[image: Error que aparece cuando no encuentra el servidor destino]

he investigado en diferentes foros, pero todos hablan de que se tienen que agregar reglas de entrada al firewall de Windows y otros que añada puertos a los servicios, pero estas son cosas que ya hice.

estoy usando maquinas virtuales para esto y estoy usando el puerto 1433.

A lo mejor la siguiente imagen puede servir de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fernando... Si tienes los dos servidores sql en distintas máquinas virtuales, puedes intentar utilizar la dirección IP en lugar del nombre de dominio?

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar, pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: De acuerdo a la imagen, tus máquinas no pueden hacer ping entre ellas. Tu problema no es con sql-server. Tu problema es con la configuración de Red de ambas máquinas virtuales. Intenta configurarles la red para utilizar NAT.

Comment: Acabo de arreglar esa parte, actualmente ya hacen bien el ping sin perder paquetes, pero siguen sin funcionar

Comment: Si estás utilizando windows 10, entra a `c:\Windows\sysWow64` y busca `SqlServerManagerXX.msc`, donde xx es el número de versión. Una vez abres la consola, ve donde dice "SQL Server Network Configuration" y confirmas que el protocolo TCP/IP está Enabled

Comment: El puerto 1433 es el que usa el motor por defecto para estar a la escucha. Para encontrar una instancia por nombre, simplemente tienes que tener corriendo el servicio SQLBrowser. Por otro lado, los puertos por defecto para un servidor reflejado son el 5022 para el principal y 5023 para el reflejado. Si tu firewall tiene cerrados esos puertos, sql server no puede hacer nada. Un ejemplo de como se realiza: https://miblogtecnico.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/alta-disponibilidad-con-mirror-en-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

puede ser las cuentas de servicio para SQL Server, utiliza una cuenta de Windows para el servicio de SQL Server, y que tenga acceso en ambas instancias.